# How to make superfish dropdown menu responsive?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, responsive-design

I am using superfish dropdown menu with skelton framework. I wanted it to work on mobiles as well. By default its showing the dropdown items but it hover over the items below it. I wants to have it in a way so that it push parent items below it. Any solution?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Update:**
See the answer by Ryan Brackett

Dropdown menus don't work well on mobile. I would suggest hiding the superfish menu on mobile and replacing it with something else.

Resources:
**Off canvas**

http://www.lukew.com/ff/entry.asp?1569

http://www.zurb.com/playground/off-canvas-layouts

**Mobile navigation patterns**

http://bradfrostweb.com/blog/web/responsive-nav-patterns/

For others looking for a solution, make sure you are using the newest jQuery. I had some older sites where I found using a newer version of jQuery made the Superfish menus work on mobile devices.

Answer (score 31):

**Here's a better answer**

I was able to convert the same HTML for Superfish into a responsive drawer menu. The JS is ultra simple and the whole thing is basically done using CSS. Check it out and let me know what you guys think!

```js
// TRIGGER ACTIVE STATE
$('#mobnav-btn').click(

  function() {
    $('.sf-menu').toggleClass("xactive");
  });



// TRIGGER DROP DOWN SUBS
$('.mobnav-subarrow').click(

  function() {
    $(this).parent().toggleClass("xpopdrop");
  });
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 20px;
}
#mobnav-btn {
  display: none;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.mobnav-subarrow {
  display: none;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  #mobnav-btn {
    display: block;
  }
  .mobnav-subarrow {
    display: block;
    background-color: #0f3975;
    opacity: .3;
    border-bottom: 1px solid white;
    border-top: 1px solid black;
    height: 20px;
    width: 30px;
    background-position: top left!important;
    position: absolute;
    top: 8px;
    right: 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-transition: all .1s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all .1s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all .1s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all .1s ease-in-out;
    transition: all .1s ease-in-out;
  }
  .sf-menu {
    width: 100%!important;
    display: none;
  }
  .sf-menu.xactive {
    display: block!important;
  }
  .sf-menu li {
    float: none!important;
    display: block!important;
    width: 100%!important;
  }
  .sf-menu li a {
    float: none!important;
  }
  .sf-menu ul {
    position: static!important;
    display: none!important;
  }
  .xpopdrop ul {
    display: block!important;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-compat-git.js"></script>
<script src="http://users.tpg.com.au/j_birch/plugins/superfish/js/superfish.js"></script>
<link href="http://users.tpg.com.au/j_birch/plugins/superfish/css/superfish.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<small>This is a responsive Superfish Menu by <a href="mailto:ryanbrackett@gmail.com">Ryan Brackett</a>. <br/>
    <br/>In this demo, you can drag the middle bar to see the responsive menu. I have already included the default css and js files for Superfish</small>

<br/>
<br/>
<div id="mobnav-btn">Button</div>
<ul class="sf-menu">
  <li><a href="#">Item 1</a>

    <div class="mobnav-subarrow"></div>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Subitem 1.1</a>

      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Subitem 1.2</a>

      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Subitem 1.3</a>

      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Subitem 1.4</a>

      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Item 2</a>

    <div class="mobnav-subarrow"></div>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Subitem 2.1</a>

      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Subitem 2.2</a>

      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Subitem 2.3</a>

      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Subitem 2.4</a>

      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Item 3</a>

    <div class="mobnav-subarrow"></div>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Subitem 3.1</a>

      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Subitem 3.2</a>

      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Subitem 3.3</a>

      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Subitem 3.4</a>

      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Item 4</a>

    <div class="mobnav-subarrow"></div>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Subitem 4.1</a>

      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Subitem 4.2</a>

      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Subitem 4.3</a>

      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Subitem 4.4</a>

      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Item 5</a>

    <div class="mobnav-subarrow"></div>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Subitem 5.1</a>

      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Subitem 5.2</a>

      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Subitem 5.3</a>

      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Subitem 5.4</a>

      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Item 6</a>

    <div class="mobnav-subarrow"></div>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Subitem 6.1</a>

      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Subitem 6.2</a>

      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Subitem 6.3</a>

      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Subitem 6.4</a>

      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Good example. Updated my answer to direct users here.

Comment: Is it possible to use 3 layers for the menu instead of 2?

Answer (score 1):

As Ed pointed out it seems problematic to solve all the different superfish/css issues for a responsive menu.

After looking through the options here and elsewhere I found a Pure CSS responsive menu which has been quicker and easier to modify than superfish, and does not have the overheads of jquery or javascript. It also has second level menus.

I checked [the demo](http://www.cssscript.com/demo/pure-css-mobile-compatible-responsive-dropdown-menu) with screenfly to check responsiveness and mobile layout before using it. The CSSscript.com version (link above) gives a horizontal responsive layout for mobiles, unlike the codepen demo page.

[image: Pure Responsive CSS menu]

[image: mobile view from screenfly, 320px wide]

The code is in a single HTML file which you can easily split into a linked CSS file, only 2 media queries manage the responsive changes and even then only with minimal changes. The '+' symbols can be deleted without issues.

Only one tiny downside: the first link downloads a HTML has a javascript at the bottom adding obvious google analytics tracking, easily removed and not on codepen.

[Explanation](http://www.cssscript.com/pure-css-mobile-compatible-responsive-dropdown-menu/) [author andor nagy - code from codepen](http://codepen.io/andornagy/pen/xhiJH)

```css
/* CSS Document */

@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans);
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Bree+Serif);

body {
 background: #212121;
 font-size:22px;
 line-height: 32px;
 color: #ffffff;
 word-wrap:break-word !important;
 font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
 }

h1 {
 font-size: 60px;
 text-align: center;
 color: #FFF;
} 

h3 {
 font-size: 30px;
 text-align: center;
 color: #FFF;
}

h3 a {
 color: #FFF;
}

a {
 color: #FFF;
}

h1 {
 margin-top: 100px;
 text-align:center;
 font-size:60px;
 font-family: 'Bree Serif', 'serif';
 }

#container {
 margin: 0 auto;
 max-width: 890px;
}

p {
 text-align: center;
}

#relatedContent {
  max-width: 800px;
  margin: 200px auto;
}

#relatedContent .item {
  max-width: 44%;
  padding: 3%;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
}

#relatedContent .item a img {
  max-width: 100%;
} 

nav { 
 margin: 50px 0;
 background-color: #E64A19;
}

nav ul {
 padding:0;
 margin:0;
 list-style: none;
 position: relative;
 }
 
nav ul li {
 display:inline-block;
 background-color: #E64A19;
 }

nav a {
 display:block;
 padding:0 10px; 
 color:#FFF;
 font-size:20px;
 line-height: 60px;
 text-decoration:none;
}

nav a:hover { 
 background-color: #000000; 
}

/* Hide Dropdowns by Default */
nav ul ul {
 display: none;
 position: absolute; 
 top: 60px;
}
 
/* Display Dropdowns on Hover */
nav ul li:hover > ul {
 display:inherit;
}
 
/* Fisrt Tier Dropdown */
nav ul ul li {
 width:170px;
 float:none;
 display:list-item;
 position: relative;
}

/* Second, Third and more Tiers */
nav ul ul ul li {
 position: relative;
 top:-60px; 
 left:170px;
}

 
/* Change this in order to change the Dropdown symbol */
li > a:after { content:  ' +'; }
li > a:only-child:after { content: ''; }
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">WordPress</a>
            <!-- First Tier Drop Down -->
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Themes</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Plugins</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Tutorials</a></li>
            </ul>        
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Web Design</a>
            <!-- First Tier Drop Down -->
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Resources</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Links</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Tutorials</a>
             <!-- Second Tier Drop Down -->
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">HTML/CSS</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">jQuery</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Other</a>
                        <!-- Third Tier Drop Down -->
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">Stuff</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Things</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Other Stuff</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Graphic Design</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Inspiration</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
  <h1>Pure CSS Drop Down Menu</h1>
<p> A simple dropdown navigation menu made with CSS Only. Dropdowns are marked with a plus sign ( + )</p>
<p>Read tutorial <a target="_blank" href="http://webdesignerhut.com/css-dropdown-menu/">here</a></p>
</div>
```

Comment: This completely misunderstands the point of the Superfish menu, which itself starts from a "pure CSS" dropdown menu and enhances it.

Comment: you should include the css and html of the demo with working responsive layout. Not the unresponsive codepen

Comment: Thanks for the info -- just responding to the specific question about Superfish.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I use:

```
    isMobile = /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent);

$(".menu a").click(function(event){
        if($(this).parents("ul").length == 1 && !$(this).hasClass("lastClick") && isMobile)
            event.preventDefault();     

        $(".menu a").removeClass("lastClick");
        $(this).addClass("lastClick");
    });
```

Replace ".menu a" with your navigation links and this snippet will navigate the user to the clicked site after the second click and the first click will only show him the subpages.

Answer (score 0):

Reshad: Simply change your CSS like this:

```css
.xpopdrop > ul {
        display: block!important;
}
```

And you will be fine.