# Responsive menu using pure css and not in javascript or jquery

Tags: css

I am using a drop down menu using pure css. I need a good responsive drop down navigation menu for the below ordinary css menu code. I need the responsive using pure css and not in javascript or jquery.

I am trying to do a responsive using pure css but i could not able to do a perfect one. Any one please help me. Thanks in advance.

```
ul.menu{
float:right;
}

ul.menu > li{
float:left;
list-style:none;    
}

ul.menu > li.current-menu-item a{
background: #5C5C5C;
color:#fff; 
}

ul.menu > li > a{
padding: 31px;
display:block;  
text-decoration: none;
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
color:#666666;
-webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
-moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
-o-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
}

ul.menu > li > a:hover{
background: #5C5C5C;
color:#fff; 
}

ul.menu > li:hover > ul.sub-menu{
display:block;
visibility:visible;
list-style:none;
opacity:1;  
top: 108px; 
}

ul.menu > li > ul.sub-menu > li > a:hover{
background:#5C5C5C;
color:#fff; 
}

ul.menu > li > ul.sub-menu{
visibility:hidden;
position: absolute;
width: 200px;
z-index: 999;
list-style:none;    
background: #f9f9f9;
border: 1px solid #e9e9e9;
border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
border-bottom: 3px solid #757575;
top:40px;
opacity:0;  
-webkit-transition: all .25s ease;
-moz-transition: all .25s ease;
-ms-transition: all .25s ease;
-o-transition: all .25s ease;
transition: all .25s ease;  
}

ul.menu > li > ul.sub-menu > li > a{
padding: 15px;
display:block;
text-decoration: none;
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
color:#666666;
-webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
-moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
-o-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
border-bottom: 1px solid #efefef;   
}
```

Comment: Please post your HTML - enough to reproduce the problem, describe the problem and what you would like the behavior to be.  If possible, a fiddle, jsbin would help as well.

Comment: <ul class="menu"><li><a href="#">Menu1</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Menu2</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Menu3</a>
<ul class="sub-menu">
 <li><a href="#">sub-menu1</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">sub-menu2</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">sub-menu3</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul> This is my html code. when i hover on menu3, the drop down list flows from top like a slide. But, in responsive i no need a hover. In case of that when clicking on a menu3 the drop down should works. Is there any code with pure css for that? @dc5

Comment: r u there. did you see the html code and what i need?

Comment: Maybe this will provide some ideas? [Pure CSS Touch Menu](http://codepen.io/micahgodbolt/pen/mnLiF)

Answer (score 0):

```
<div>
    <ul class="mymenu">
        <li><a class="dropdown" href="#">Menu 1</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Sub-menu 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sub-menu 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sub-menu  3</a></li>
            </ul>
            </li>

    </ul>
</div>


div ul {
    -webkit-font-smoothing:antialiased;
    text-shadow:0 1px 0 #FFF;
    background: #ddd;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
div li {
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
    min-width: 25%;
}
div a {
    background: #ddd;
    color: #444;
    display: block;
    font: bold 16px/50px sans-serif;
    padding: 0 25px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    -webkit-transition: all .25s ease;
       -moz-transition: all .25s ease;
        -ms-transition: all .25s ease;
         -o-transition: all .25s ease;
            transition: all .25s ease;
}
div .dropdown:after {
    content: ' ▶';
}
div .dropdown:hover:after{
    content:'\25bc'
}
div li:hover a {
    background: #ccc;
}
div li ul {
    float: left;
    left: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 35px;
    visibility: hidden;
    z-index: 1;
    -webkit-transition: all .25s ease;
       -moz-transition: all .25s ease;
        -ms-transition: all .25s ease;
         -o-transition: all .25s ease;
            transition: all .25s ease;
}
div li:hover ul {
    opacity: 1;
    top: 50px;
    visibility: visible;
}
div li ul li {
    float: none;
    width: 100%;
}
div li ul a:hover {
    background: #bbb;
}

/* Clearfix */

.mymenu:after, .cf:before {
    content:"";
    display:table;
}
.mymenu:after {
    clear:both;
}
.mymenu {
    zoom:1;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @srk. It works fine when hovering on a main menu for a sub menu. I need not an hovering one. When clicking on a main menu i need a drop down.

Comment: @user2644743 - Are you looking for a CSS solution or using Javascript / JQuery will work for you? you need to add click events using any of the script to make it work onClick, by just toggling the class names which is now triggered on hover of li using CSS.

Comment: this menu works well http://stackoverflow.com/a/32470745/4258817 - demo link is in the answer for testing before you decide