# Do I need to use a JQuery plug-in for a responsive menu?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this Jquery code for a navigation menu.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery(".menu-trigger").click(function() {
        jQuery(".menu").slideToggle(100, function() {
            jQuery(this).toggleClass("menu-expanded").css("display", "");
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

I also have this code. Is this plug-in code necessary or is there an alternative?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Many kinds of responsive menus can be done using pure CSS.

Comment: The plugin is just javascript. There's nothing stopping you from implementing it in your own code, except maybe your programming talent and the time available.

Comment: Do you want a jQuery plug-in for a responsive menu ?

Comment: thanks, I want to eliminate render-blocking, so have inlined the first code but the 1.11.1 I don't fully understand it's purpose or know of an alternative.

Comment: @Paul The first bit of code you posted will not work unless it is put after the second, because the jQuery file is required for jQuery to work. If you want to avoid render blocking, but the JS below the content on your page, at the end of the <body> tag.

Comment: Though I'm not sure how you've learned about render-blocking and still don't know what jQuery is and how it works. Read the JS about to learn how to debug JS in the browser > http://stackoverflow.com/tags/javascript/info

Comment: Thanks for the help. I know very little about JQ so will read the link, I just got some code on the web which seemed to work! So is the 1.11.1 code a common 'script' that is used in conjunction other small JQ scripts?

Comment: this answer has a pure CSS responsive menu so no need for jquery or javascript, and easy to modify too http://stackoverflow.com/a/32470745/4258817 - demo link is in the answer for testing before you decide

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the same menu using just CSS. No need for jQuery/javascript.
Example tutorial: http://medialoot.com/blog/how-to-create-a-responsive-navigation-menu-using-only-css/

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I understand your question correctly:

You don't "need" jQuery, it can't do anything pure JS can't do. If you want to build a responsive menu, do that, if you want to use a library for it, do that. You can do this with JS or pure CSS depending on what design you want. jQuery can certainly make it easier to do this with JS, if you go that route.

You'll learn more and have more control and an easier time customizing it if you do it yourself, and for most small components like this, I'd go that way.

Answer (score 0):

JQuery can be considered a library that creates shorthand for various JavaScript functionality. You can do anything in JavaScript that you can do in JQuery. So no, it's not necessary, but it does make things a lot easier. If you're looking for other response-oriented motion libraries without the overhead of JQuery, I would suggest velocityjs:  http://julian.com/research/velocity/

Though I have to warn you, the syntax is mostly the same with a few tweaks. If you're moving away from JQuery due to the format I would suggest a different path.

You can also create responsive menus in CSS though that'll require a different frame of reference than that of JavaScript. Here's a tutorial on the subject to get you started: http://cssmenumaker.com/blog/creating-a-responsive-menu