# Menu stays open on click

Tags: css, html, drop-down-menu

I have a menu with drop down statement on hover the problem is that when i remove the mouse it hides again, can someone help me keep the sub menu open  when i click the option on the main menu?

It show´s when mouse hover but i need it to stay open even after i remove the mouse cursor.

thanks

```
            #cssmenu > ul {
              position: relative;
              z-index: 999;
              float: left;
              border-bottom:2px solid lightblue;
            }
            #cssmenu > ul li {
              float: left;
              min-height: 0px;
              line-height: 1.3em;
              vertical-align: middle;
              padding: 0px;
            }
            #cssmenu > ul li.hover,
            #cssmenu > ul li:hover {
              z-index: 599;
              cursor: default;
            }
            #cssmenu > ul ul {
              visibility: hidden;
              position: absolute;
              top: 100%;
              left: 0;
              z-index: 598;
            }
            #cssmenu > ul ul li {
              float: none;
            }

            #cssmenu > ul li:hover > ul {
              visibility: visible;
              border-bottom:2px solid lightblue;
              color: white;
            }

            #cssmenu {
              width: auto;
              background: black;
              font-size: 13px;
              color:white;
              top:0px;
            }
            #cssmenu > ul {
              padding: 0 1px;
              display: block;
              float: none;
              zoom: 1;
            }
            #cssmenu > ul:before {
              content: '';
              display: block;
            }
            #cssmenu > ul:after {
              content: '';
              display: table;
              clear: both;
            }

            #cssmenu ul ul {
              margin: 0 10px;
              padding: 0 10px;
              float: none;
              background: black;
              border-bottom:2px solid lightblue;
              border-left: 1px solid lightblue;
              border-right: 1px solid lightblue;
              border-top: none;
              right: 0;
              left: 0;
              visibility: hidden;




            <div id='cssmenu' style="opacity: 0.5;filter: alpha(opacity=50);align-top:0px;color:white;">
            <ul>
               <li class='activeM'><a class="inicio" href='#'><span>Home</span></a></li>
               <li class='activeM'><a class="competencias" href='#'><span>Competências</span></a>
                  <ul>
                     <li class='active'><a class="saude" href='#'><span>Saúde</span></a></li>
                     <li class='active'><a class="ecosocial" href='#'><span>Economia Social</span></a></li>
                     <li class='active'><a class="desnvsustent" href='#'><span>Desenvolvimento Sustentado</span></a></li>
                  </ul>
               </li>
               </div>
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't think you can do it with basic CSS. I'm pretty sure you're gonna need some javascript

Comment: Yeha, I "think" you will need an `onClick()`

Comment: Iv been trying with the target css function but with no result :(

Comment: this answer has a pure CSS responsive menu and works well in all sizes http://stackoverflow.com/a/32470745/4258817 - demo link is in the answer for testing before you decide

Answer (score 1):

The most recent comment seems to make this more clear that you're looking for a visual fading effect. You're right. A transition would be a good way to go.

You'll need to use opacity as well as visibility. I mocked up an example here: http://jsbin.com/cesacu/1/edit?html,css,output

You may want to play with the [transition timing function](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/t/transition-timing-function/) or duration to get the effect you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** Thanks for the demo. It seems to have appropriate behavior at larger screen sizes, when the menu is all on one level. You're right that there's a problem when the menu goes to two levels on smaller screens.Is that the situation where you're experiencing the real problem?

[I found this CodePen that shows one way to make a responsive two-level menu like this.](http://codepen.io/JHolah/pen/HkLlh) If you need a pure-CSS menu, try searching for "responsive pure css mega menu". There look to be some other options there.

---

*Initial answer*:

I do think you'll need Javascript as Hakim said. One option would be to add classes that replace your `:hover` pseudo classes, then use a jQuery call to add those classes to the menu.

This example from a [2009 CSS Tricks post](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/addingremoving-class-on-hover/), tweaked for your case:

```
$('#cssmenu > ul li:hover > ul').hover(
  function(){ 
    $(this).children().addClass('visible');
  }
)
```

It looks like you'll also need to add a class directly on `$(this)` for the `#cssmenu > ul li.hover` selector. You would then need another command, such as `$(your-selector).click(function(){ $(this).removeClass('visible'))` to make it go away again.

On a more general note, it does seem a little odd to want a sub-menu to stay open even when you leave it. Unless there's a third level menu, that is.

Comment: Theres no third nlevel menu the problem is that when moving to the submenu if the mouse leave the horizontal bar it closes and i know people will complain about that. :( @alexbea

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean. I put your code in a JSBin and I'm able to easily move my mouse from the top menu into the sub-menu and the sub-menu then stays open. http://jsbin.com/qomaqolowe/edit?html,css,output

Comment: It stay open with mouse hover, the problem is that some sub menu are to extense and when moving to the last submenu option sometimes its hard not to go out of the sub menu or accidently move to another menu and then changing the submenu

Comment: I may need you to clarify more in your original post. If you are really asking how to make the sub menu a larger target for hovering over, that's a different question.

Comment: No, what i need is. when i click on the menu it should open the submenu and stay that, in this moment when i remove my mouse cursor from the menu, the submenu closes.

Comment: here is the problem : http://www.hostelpet.com/teste/teste.html  please note that when you move the mouse out of the menu the submenu disapears and i need it to stay visible.  thanks @alexbea

Comment: I just whanted something like this https://www.jogossantacasa.pt/ after a few seconds the sub menu closes, what i now have closes the second whe move the cursor out. cant this be maide with css, maybe with transition?

Comment: I think I understand now. I've added a separate answer for that.