# Minimal Responsive Menu (Pure CSS) in not working on android default browser

Tags: android, html, css, browser

I use Minimal Responsive Menu (Pure CSS) in a project as navigation Menu.

http://codepen.io/nickisix/pen/julqA

I test this navigation in most Useful browser. Results in google chrome, Mozilla Firefox and opera is OK, but in android (4.2) default browser when click on ≡, nothings happened. How I can fix this?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is an option for you, but the Pure CSS Mobile-compatible drop-down menu by Andor Nagy described in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32470745/4258817) works well on a kitkat stock browser. A 'what is my browser tool'  said it was using a Chrome v30 user agent.  You can test via the demo page before. - http://www.cssscript.com/demo/pure-css-mobile-compatible-responsive-dropdown-menu

Answer (score 0):

I think you've forgotten something like

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

in your head. It tells the device to use media queries, which are included in your css. This may fix the problem.

Comment: No, I put "viewport" in head of html page, also google mobile-friendly Tools detects that my website is responsive, But this navigation work on on chrome, Firefox, Opera (even android app of these browser) and it not work on android default browser.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't accurately test this because I don't have an android phone....however, try using the responsive inspector in google chrome or Firefox and see if that produces any errors. If that doesn't work, maybe your phone is part of the problem? Like a desktop spoofing tool?