# Want to make Superfish vertical menu Responsive

Tags: menu, responsive, superfish

I am using super fish vertical menu but its not working on responsive view. Need to fix this  for responsive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Media queries will help you make it responsive
Have a look at this [codepen](https://codepen.io/Imperative/pen/qaskf) another great example given in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15928198/2299040)

following code is taken from codepen which makes the menu responsive.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    body {
        margin: 0; } }

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    header.global nav #hamburger {
        display: block; } }
header.global nav ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 25px;
    display: block; }
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    header.global nav ul {
        display: none;
        margin: 7px 0;
        padding: 0; } }

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    header.global nav ul li {
        width: 100%;
        background: #2d2d2d;
        border-left: none;
        border-right: none;
        border-top: 1px solid #474747;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #141414; }
    header.global nav ul li:first-child {
        border-top: none; }
    header.global nav ul li:last-child {
        border-bottom: none; } }

@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
    header.global nav ul li:hover > a {
        position: relative; }
    header.global nav ul li:hover > a:after {
        content: "";
        position: absolute;
        left: 20px;
        top: 40px;
        border-width: 0 8px 8px;
        border-style: solid;
        border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) #ef3636;
        display: block;
        width: 0;
        z-index: 999; } }
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    header.global nav ul li ul {
        width: 100% !important;
    }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
    header.global nav ul li ul li:hover a:after {
        border: none; } }
```